# how to use if #available(iOS 16.0, *) for a VARIABLE. not in the body?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to not compile the env var requestReview if the ios version is < 15.0

if #available works in the body but doesnt' work for variables, what can I do?

struct HomeView11labs: View {

```
//for the review 
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview: RequestReviewAction
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that will check the iOS version and run the review function accordingly - make sure it's a `@MainActor` function to run it on the Main thread.

Edit - So I found out that we can use the `@Environment` only inside a view and not a function hence I put in in a view modifier that will run the request review function depending on the iOS version whenever the `@Binding` variable is changed and now this should mostly give you what you want.

```
    @available(iOS 16, *)
    struct ReviewModifier: ViewModifier {
        
        @Binding var canRequestReview: Bool
        @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview
    
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .onChange(of: canRequestReview) { newValue in
                    if newValue {
                        requestReview.callAsFunction()
                    } else {
                        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    extension View {
        
        @ViewBuilder func requestReview(_ canRequestReview: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
            if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                modifier(ReviewModifier(canRequestReview: canRequestReview))
            } else {
                self
            }
        }
}
```